# How to set button text dynamically with text from database in C#?

Tags: mysql, c#-3.0

I'm trying to create an application where the button text is dynamically set.

[image]

The above blank buttons are supposed to be set once an item is added on the database. For example, I added 'New Item Here' on the database and it should look like the image below.

[image]

So far, what I do is add an item on the database and manually set the button text which requires rebuilding/reinstalling the application.

Is there a way I can automatically set the button text? 
Or perhaps, make a populated listview that looks like a group of buttons?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Establish a connection to the database, then pull out all the required data from it and assign each value to the button name

//Set button name

```
ButtonName.Text = variable name that holds the string from database ;
```

Comment: I did that sir, but the problem is I got a lot of Buttons to set value. Like ButtonName1.Text="Item1", ButtonName2.Text="Item2"..until Button10. Is there a way I can put the statements into a loop so that it will not consume long lines?

Answer (score 0):

Use this loop Statement

The data array represents buttonNames from database

```
 string[] data = { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };

int i = 1;
while (i < 11)
     {
 foreach (var x in data)
 {
         String button = "button";
         String Button = (button + i).ToString();
         Button.Text=x;
         i++;
     }
 }
```

In your GUI design, give the buttons names like "button1","button2" ,"button3"  etc

Comment: Thank you sir. How am I going to do line Button1.Text = "item1"? It can't be the string see above.

Comment: @benziv  the edited code above.. If you run into errors, let me know